# Remove Node in Doubly Linked List (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list, structure, doubly-linked-list

This is my remove function for deleting a node with the element `item`. I'm getting a seg fault and I'm pretty sure it's because temp -> prev is the front sentinel so it's not technically in the doubly linked list. And if that's correct, how do I actually go about preventing this? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Just updated the code, but still coming out with a Seg fault

```
void list::remove(const list_element & item)
{
  list_node* temp = _front;
  for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
      if (temp -> next -> data == item)
      {
       if (temp -> prev == _front)
        {    
          _front = temp -> next;
        }
      else if (temp -> next == _rear)
        {    
          temp -> prev -> next = _rear;
        }
      else
        {
          temp -> prev -> next = temp -> next;
          temp -> next -> prev = temp -> prev;
        }
    }
      delete temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommend confirming your suspicions with the debugger the should have come with your development environment. The debugger is likely the best programming productivity tool you'll ever find, so the sooner you get good as its use the more time you'll have for other things.

Comment: That said, it looks like you are checking the next node to see if it should be removed, then  removing the current node instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to go through the list node by node using a `while()` loop. Since `_front` is a sentinel you don't need an explicit check for whether the `next` or `prev` node is the head or tail.

```c++
void list::remove(const list_element& item) {
  list_node* current = _front;
  while (current->next != nullptr) {
    if (current->next->data == item) {
      current->next = current->next->next;
      if (current->next != nullptr) {
        delete current->next->prev;
        current->next->prev = current;
      }
      break;
    }
    current = current->next;
  }
  // update pointer to rear if it changed
  if (current->next == nullptr)
    _rear = current;
}
```

Comment: @MikeLandry No, `sentinel->next` is the head (front) of the linked list. A sentinel is just a dummy node used to make things like like removal/insertion/lookup simpler as we don't have to worry about whether it has a `->next` pointer (because it always does). It always resides before the actual linked list.

Comment: @MikeLandry I assumed you had a `list_node* sentinel` inside your linked list class that pointed to the beginning of the list (`sentinel->next == _front`)

Comment: In my code `_front -> next` is the first node in the list though. So technically isn't the `sentinel` in your code referring to the `_front` in mine?

Comment: @MikeLandry If I'm understanding this correctly, you are using the `_front` pointer as the actual sentinel node in your program, and `_front->next` is the actual head (beginning) of the linked list? In that case, yes, `sentinel` is just referring to `_front`. I'll update my code.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. Only problem is I'm still getting that annoying seg fault, even with your code.

Comment: @MikeLandry My code isn't giving a seg fault when I use it (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce831a37eb44c2cf). Are you sure you've debugged and found it's coming from the remove function?

Comment: You're right. It was a problem with my output function. Anyways, thanks for the help!